# How do I copy a discriminated union case value?

Tags: f#

How do I copy a discriminated union case value?

**The following code has some duplication:**

```
let move (direction:Direction) (checker:Checker) =
    match checker with
    | Red   xy -> Red   { xy with X=2; Y=2 }
    | Black xy -> Black { xy with X=2; Y=2 }
```

Specifically, I don't want to specify the type of checker just to set its record value. Hence, I don't care if the checker is red or black. I would like to just copy the checker case value and update its position.

**I would rather do something like this:**

```
let move (direction:Direction) (checker:Checker) =
    match checker with
    | _ xy -> _ { xy with X=2; Y=2 }
```

**Here's my test:**

```
[<Test>]
let ``move checker``() =
    Black { X=1; Y=1 } |> move NorthEast 
                       |> should equal (Black { X=2; Y=2 })
```

**Appendix:**

```
module Test3

open NUnit.Framework
open FsUnit

type Position = { X:int; Y:int }
type Checker = | Red of Position | Black of Position

type Direction =
    | NorthEast
    | NorthWest
    | SouthEast
    | SouthWest

(* Functions *)
let move (direction:Direction) (checker:Checker) =
    match checker with
    | Red   xy -> Red   { xy with X=2; Y=2 }
    | Black xy -> Black { xy with X=2; Y=2 }

[<Test>]
let ``move checker``() =
    Black { X=1; Y=1 } |> move NorthEast 
                       |> should equal (Black { X=2; Y=2 })
```

Comment: Your data types are inside out. If this is your use case, you should define the checker as `{ pos: Position; color: Color }`, then you can update the position without touching the color.

Comment: Ahh... That makes sense. By the way can union case values be copied regardless of my design issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing you're asking for can't be done in F# without reflection trickery.

Here a common sense explanation: it is very rare that union cases have the exact same data under them. When this is the case, it probably indicates that the union cases themselves are just a "tags" used to mark the data, and thus should be encoded "alongside" the data, not "around" it. And since such union types are rare exceptions, it doesn't make sense to invent language machinery to support them.

This rationalization applies to your specific case nicely: the color of the checker is a "tag" that should be "next to" the position, rather than "wrapping" it. If you define a checker as `{ pos: Position; color: Color }`, then you'll be able to update the position without touching the color.

Comment: Technically that's feasible without reflection (I don't say it should be done though) for Union case with the same data we can do a function (or active pattern function) which return the constructeur for the right case something along `let (|CheckerCtor|) = function Red _ -> Red | Black _ -> Black` and then is usable like this `let move dir (CheckerCtor ctor) = ctor dir` (we can also extract the data associated with each case if we wanted ; but that's really convoluted)

Comment: This is similar (in some sense) to what scrwtp wrote in his answer, and my objection will be similar as well.

Comment: sure thing ; I never say it should be used ; just that the bit about "only done with reflection" is in a sense misleading in your answer

Comment: I would argue that it's not misleading. The original attempt that Scott made consisted of creating a function that deals with the cases one by one. Scott was unsatisfied with that and asked for a better way. Your suggestion also consists of creating such function (even if in a better way that Scott's original attempt), and so won't qualify as an answer to the original question. Scott wanted to somehow do it without mentioning each case individually, and _that_ is not possible without reflection.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I buy the "tag should be next to the position rather than wrapping it" reasoning. Sure, this example may be overly simple, but it's a very valid scenario when some of your union cases share a piece of data that you want to operate on in a transparent way.

A standard FP pattern is to have a map function over the type. For instance, you can have a specialized map function defined on your union type that knows how to update the position for each of your cases:

```
type Checker = 
    | Orange of Position 
    | Blue   of (Position * DateTime)
    | Bacon  of bool
    member this.MapPosition (f: Position -> Position) = 
        match this with
        | Orange pos     -> Orange (f pos)
        | Blue (pos, dt) -> Blue (f pos, dt)
        | Bacon x        -> Bacon x
```

And use it like this:

```
let move (direction:Direction) (checker:Checker) =
    checker.MapPosition(fun _ -> { X=2; Y=2 })
```

Comment: That's not what Scott was asking. He wanted a magical language feature to do it, and that doesn't exist. Of course you can do whatever if you're willing to hide all the ugliness away in utility functions. But the ugliness doesn't go away, it's just hidden.

Comment: Also, notice how your example doesn't actuallyl have the exact same data under every case, so this is not the "tag" situation I was describing.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: there's a wide spectrum of things between "magical language feature" and "having to copy-paste the match all across the code". What OP was looking for was a way to reduce code duplication, and I suggested a general, structured approach to this kind of problem. I don't see ugliness here.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin: and while your advice is fair for this particular example, I wouldn't be so quick to call it a flawed design. Discriminated unions **are** in fact tags on data. The Red-Black example can be disputed because of how simple it is, but it's not fundamentally wrong.